# Visual Studio Code Project Importing from Wrong Directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import

I have the below directory structure. In my test2.py file, I am importing resource.py. It is however referencing resource.py from Folder1 instead of Folder2. Can someone explain to me what is happening, and/or how I can import from the correct directory?

-Folder1 (Original folder)
--resource.py
--Folder
---test1.py

-Folder2 (Copied from folder 1)
--resource.py (modified global variable values)
--Folder
---test2.py

**Update:** I was able to workaround my problem by adding the below snippet of code. Any additional suggestions are welcome, so I don't need to apply this code to each .py file in Folder2 that needs resource.py

```
import sys
sys.path.remove('path\\to\\not\\wanted\\directory')
sys.path.add('path\\to\\wanted\\import\\source')
```

Answer (score 0):

After `Python: Clear Internal Extension Cache` from Command Palette, specify the clear path about importing the module with the following code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("./")
import folder2.resource as f2r
```

See result:

[image]